# Moved from VS 2010 to VS 2015, slower WinForms project building

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I've just transformed my WinForms project from Visual Studio 2010 to VS2015. Building in vs2010 took almost no time. Building it in Visual Studio 2015 takes 2 or three seconds, let's just say more than it took in vs2010. Why? It irritates me. the project is small: e.g. 10 forms, 10 classes, 2 dlls connected.

Comment: Check you anti-virus.

Comment: @SLaks Avast, real-time file system pre-open/exec scan is off.

Comment: That scourge to humanity also injects VS and slows down its named pipe interop with the compiler.  Get rid of it asap.

Comment: @HansPassant You mean Avast slows down VS even while turned off? Why had not slowed vs2010 then?